# Does Windows 10 have the ability to transform selected text to uppercase, lowercase etc?

Tags: windows, windows-10

As the title says... Does Windows 10 have the ability to transform selected text to uppercase, lowercase etc? Is there any keyboard shortcut or something?

For example, let's say I have a folder by the name "empty folder" and I want to rename it to "EMPTY FOLDER" at once. Not by typing this text again.

Comment: Microsoft Word has this ability (Select text then press Shift+F3) but I do not believe it is built into Windows itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature built in to Windows (neither 10 nor any other version).

To do this, maybe make an AutoHotkey script that sends a Ctrl+X, alters the text in clipboard, then sends a Ctrl+V, or something like that.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you very much!!!